# mutagen EasyID3 adds metadata except the album name

Tags: mutagen

When I write the metadata to an MP3 file using the Python library mutagen, and then open the file in VLC and look at the media information in VLC, I see the Title, Artist and Track number set correctly as in the image below. However I don't see the Album set.
[image: metadata in VLC]

Why is the Album not showing up? Below is my code using mutagen.

```
# Create file if it does not exist yet.
try:
    # If file doesn't exist, then the exception below will be thrown.
    meta = EasyID3(mp3_filename)
except mutagen.id3.ID3NoHeaderError:
    # Create file.
    meta = mutagen.File(mp3_filename, easy=True)
    meta.add_tags()
    meta.save()

audio = EasyID3(mp3_filename)
audio["title"] = 'Part 1'
audio["tracknumber"] = '1'
audio["author"] = 'Google'
audio["artist"] = 'Google'
audio["album"] = 'BSRS'

audio.save()
```